# NixOS on MacBook: how to enable sudden motion sensor?

Tags: macintosh, sensors, nixos

How to make sure in NixOS on a MacBook that the sudden motion sensor and the relevant disk protections are enabled?

It seems that I need the **applesmc** module for this, but I couldn't find how to install it in NixOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the applesmc module by adding this to your configuration.nix

```
boot.kernelModules = [ "applesmc" ];
```

Comment: Thanks, i did this.  Can you by any chance suggest a simple way to test that it works?

Comment: Try dropping your laptop a few times. ;)

Comment: Does it matter by the way if i include it in `boot.kernelModules` or `boot.initrd.kernelModules`?